# firefox add-on sdk worker.port events are not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

it´s me again :-|

I can´t get the events working, which I can use with worker.port.on(...).

See my code:

main.js:

```
// import the modules we need
var data = require('self').data;
var {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
var mediator = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
var self = require('self');
var panel = require("sdk/panel");
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

// exports.main is called when extension is installed or re-enabled
exports.main = function(options, callbacks)
{
    tabs.on("ready",
            function (activeTab)
            {
                var worker = activeTab.attach({contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("inject.js")]});
                worker.port.on("testmain",
                                function(data)
                                {
                                    self.port.emit("testcontent", "bladibla");
                                }
                            );
            }
        );
};
```

inject.js:

```
self.port.on("testcontent",
function (data)
{
window.alert(data);
});
self.port.emit("testmain");
```

Help would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: What part doesn't work? At what point does the event chain not get to?

Answer (score 1):

The following call:

```
self.port.emit("testcontent", "bladibla");
```

Should be:

```
worker.port.emit("testcontent", "bladibla");
```